# change height and direction of triangles in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a basic Bar chart with red and green triangles. Red triangle on negative comparison of data and green triangle if the data is positive. The green triangle should always point upwards and red downwards at the bottom of the bar and if the data is neutral the circle should be displayed. I'm unable to align the arrow/triangle to bottom(touch x-axis) as well as rotate the arrow to point up or down based on condition. Here is my code

```
svg.selectAll("line.arrow")
    .data(input.filter(function (d) { return d.AverageValue}))
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "arrow")
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
        return xScale(d.AppName) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return xScale(d.AppName) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return yScale(20);//bring arrows to bottom
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        var getValue = d.AverageValue;
        if (getValue >= 0) {
            return yScale(10)-37;
        } else {
            return yScale(23) - 6;
        }
    }) 
    .attr("marker-end", function (d) {
        var getValue = d.ComparedToPreviousMonth;
        if (getValue < 0) {
            return "url(#redArrow)";
        } else if (getValue > 0) {
            return "url(#greenArrow)";
        }
    });
```

The entire code is in fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/911vgmp1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [one way](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/911vgmp1/3/). I've

- Split the green and red arrows so they can have separate transforms
- translated the markers down to the bottom of the bars
- Made the markers overflow visible so they still display after the data is translated

  ```
                          // add text and arrow
                          svg.selectAll("line.arrow")
                              .data(["red"])
                              .enter()
                            .append("defs").append("marker")
                              .attr("id", function (d) {

                                  return d + "Arrow";

                              })
                              .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                              .attr("refX", 8)
                              .attr("markerWidth", 12)
                              .attr("markerHeight", 20)
                              .attr("orient", "auto")
                              .attr("overflow", "visible")
                            .append("svg:path")
                              .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
                              .attr("transform", "rotate(90, 5, 0)  translate(56, 0)")
                              .attr("class", function (d) {
                                  return "marker_" + d;

                              });

                          svg.selectAll("line.arrow")
                              .data(["green"])
                              .enter()
                            .append("defs").append("marker")
                              .attr("id", function (d) {

                                  return d + "Arrow";

                              })
                              .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                              .attr("refX", 8)
                              .attr("markerWidth", 12)
                              .attr("markerHeight", 20)
                              .attr("orient", "auto")
                              .attr("overflow", "visible")
                            .append("svg:path")
                              .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
                              .attr("transform", "rotate(270, 5, 0) translate(-56, 0)")
                              .attr("class", function (d) {
                                  return "marker_" + d;

                              });
  ```

Comment: @user4895544: Although this might work it seems to be a workaround circumventing the root problem. I have posted another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30460493/4235784) which you might find helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the generated svg output you will notice that the lines you are using for setting your markers are geometrically points rather than lines, i.e. `x1` equals `x2` and `y1` equals `y2`:

```
<line class="arrow" x1="33.5" x2="33.5" y1="296" y2="296" marker-end="url(#redArrow)"></line>
```

Because this *line / point* doesn't have any direction there is no way to determine the orientation of the marker. Hence, your `orient="auto"` will not rotate the markers appropriately.

In the generator function for `attr("marker-end")` you are using `d.ComparedToPreviousMonth` which works fine determining which marker to use. The generator function for `.attr("y2")`, however,  uses `d.AverageValue` to calcutate `y2` and, thus, the direction of the line and the orientation of the marker. Since the `AverageValue`s are all positive there is no change in direction of your lines / markers.

You may fix this by adjusting the `y1` and `y2` generators to:

```
.attr("y1", function (d) {
    return h;
})
.attr("y2", function (d) {
    var getValue = d.ComparedToPreviousMonth;
    if (getValue < 0) {
         return h - .001;
    } else {
        return h + .001;
    }
})
```

For the purists the `y2` generator may even be shortened to:

```
.attr("y2", function (d) {
    return d.ComparedToPreviousMonth < 0 ? h - .001 : h + .001;
})
```

With that in place, you'll just have to set different `refX` values for your markers to visually position them on the x-axis:

```
.attr("refX", function(d) {
    return d == "red" ? 0 : 10;
})
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/911vgmp1/4/).

Comment: Thank you Altocumulus, for the answer. I guess this is very helpful to me once I integrate it with dynamic data and hence avoiding the workaround.

Comment: Have one more issue. Need to draw a horizontal line for the column AverageOrganizationValue(which is constant across array). Is there any available example you can suggest.

Comment: I updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/911vgmp1/6/). Please consider putting this or any other problem into another SO question.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Fixed the triangle issue with lil tweak.